# Parse text file from content-type=application/zip and base64 encoding in AWS SES

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip, aws-lambda

On amazon SES, I have a rule to save incoming emails to S3 buckets. Amazon saves these in MIME format.

These emails have a `.txt` in attachment that will be shown in the MIME file as `content-type=text/plain`, `Content-Disposition=attachment ... .txt`, and `Content-Transfer-Encoding=quoted-printable` or `bases64`.

I am able to parse it fine using python.

I have a problem decoding the content of the `.txt` file attachment when this is compressed (i.e., `content-type: applcation/zip`), as if the encoding wasn't `base64`.

My code:

```
import base64
s = unicode(base64.b64decode(attachment_content), "utf-8")
```

throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 796, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

Below are the first few lines of the "base64" string in `attachment_content`, which btw has length 53683 + "==" at the end, and I thought that the length of a base64 should be a multiple of 4 (??). 
So maybe the decoding is failing because the compression is changing `attachment_content` and I need some other operation before/after decoding it? I have really no idea..

```
UEsDBBQAAAAIAM9Ah0otgkpwx5oAADMTAgAJAAAAX2NoYXQudHh0tL3bjiRJkiX23sD+g0U3iOxu
REWGu8c1l2Ag8lKd0V2ZWajM3kLuC6Hubu5uFeZm3nYJL6+n4T4Ry8EOdwCSMyQXBRBLgMQ+7CP5
QPBj5gdYn0CRI6JqFxWv7hlyszursiJV1G6qonI5cmQyeT6dPp9cnCaT6Yvp5Yvz6xfJe7cp8P/k
1SbL8xfJu0OSvUvr2q3TOnFVWjxrknWZFeuk2VRlu978s19MRvNMrHneOv51SOZlGUtMLYnfp0nd

...
```

I have also tried used "latin-1", but get gibberish.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that, after conversion, I was dealing with a zipped file in format, like "`PK \x03 \x04 \X3C \Xa \x0c ...`", and I needed to unzip it before transforming it to UTF-8 unicode.

This code worked for me:

```
import email

# Parse results from email
received_email = email.message_from_string(email_text)
for part in received_email.walk():
    c_type = part.get_content_type()
    c_enco = part.get('Content-Transfer-Encoding')

    attachment_content = part.get_payload()

    if c_enco == 'base64':
        import base64
        decoded_file = base64.b64decode(attachment_content)
        print("File decoded from base64")

        if c_type == "application/zip":
            from cStringIO import StringIO
            import zipfile
            zfp = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO(decoded_file), "r")
            unzipped_list = zfp.open(zfp.namelist()[0]).readlines()
            decoded_file = "".join(unzipped_list)
            print('And un-zipped')

    result = unicode(decoded_file, "utf-8")
```